# Sorting values in each key in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash in my Ruby code whose values for each key are multiple arrays. I'd like to sort the values the values for each key. Actually I'd like to sort each element in each array so that every single element from all of the arrays are sorted. I was thinking about making the values a single array for each key and sorting that. Is there a way to do this easily?

Comment: Please post an example of input and output data. Also given some the methods added to Hash the ruby version would be a useful addition to the post as well

Comment: While you are posting an example, take a look at the doc: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html

Comment: `array_key.flatten.sort`?

Comment: I don't understand your question. @engineersmnky has asked for an example, I expect because he (and others who upvoted his comment) don't understand your question either. I'm downvoting and voting to close because you've seen that request but decided not to respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael
I suppose  that you have following hash `data = {:a=>[5, 2, 1, 3, 4], :b=>[7, 1, 3, 4]}`
Now to sort them:

1) if you want to sort the values corresponding to keys then use

`data.update(data){ |k,v| v.sort }`

which results `{:a=>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], :b=>[1, 3, 4, 7]}`

2) if you want get all sorted values then use
`data.flat_map(&:last).sort`

this will result : `[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7]` `#sorted values array`

Comment: Consider `data.transform_values(&:sort)`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `flat_map` might be a good place to start: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map